# Cannot remove 1px white strip - even after adding highlightthickness?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, border

I followed this example since I was having issues removing white borders.

OP was told to add highlightthickness and change x0, y0 and y1 to 0.  This worked all but for 1 px of white space/line?  Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.configure(bg='#333333')
master.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
TopLevel.overrideredirect(True)

w = Canvas(master, width=150, height=40, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge',)
w.config()
w.pack(fill='both')

color = 100
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
x1 = 150
y1 = 0

while y0 < 20 :
    r = color
    g = color
    b = color
    rgb = r, g, b
    Hex = '#%02x%02x%02x' % rgb
    w.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1,fill=str(Hex), width=1)
    color = color - 2
    y0 = y0 + 1
    y1 = y1 + 1

color = 10

while y0 < 40 :
    r = color
    g = color
    b = color
    rgb = r, g, b
    Hex = '#%02x%02x%02x' % rgb
    w.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1,fill=str(Hex), width=1)
    color = color + 4
    y0 = y0 + 1
    y1 = y1 + 1

mainloop()
```

[image: small remaining white border]

Comment: This code won't run, there are several issues.

Comment: Hi.  This snippet was provided as a solution to why white border exists and how to rid - problem is, it doesn't 'completely' remove the white - my img attachment shows the white pixels in the far left.  I presume it's due to the entire thing being garbage.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 4. and 7. line, because PyCharm gave me an error:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
tl = Toplevel() # delete me if the issue still remains :)
master.configure(bg='#333333')
master.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
tl.overrideredirect(True) # delete me if the issue still remains :)
...
```

if the issue still remains, try deleting 4. and 7. line.
Shouldn't make any problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  See above comment! problem still persists in the example provided.  I just moved on to the next! Cheers